# Laravel 4.2 Eager Loading 4 tables

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, eager-loading

I've got a problem I've not faced before with Eager Loading in Laravel.

I have the following table structure

```
- Letter
    id,
    sentence_id

- Sentence
    id,
    paragraph_id

- Paragraph
    id,
    book_id

- Book
    id
```

**belongsTo/belongsToMany:**

- `letter->belongsToMany('Sentence')`
- `sentence->belongsTo('Paragraph')`
- `paragraph->belongsTo('Book')`

**has/hasMany:**

- `book->hasMany('Paragraph')`
- `paragraph->hasMany('Sentence')`
- `sentence->hasMany('Letter')`

This all works great. However, if I want to get all the letters in the book, I have can't seem to figure out the correct way to do this.

I've tried `hasManyThrough` but quickly realized that does not serve the purpose I'm trying to achieve.

I then thought I could use `Eager Loading` WITH `hasManyThrough` something to the effect of.

```
public function sentences(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('Sentence', 'Paragraph');
}
```

Which I could then do something like:

```
Book::sentences()->with(['letters' => function($q) use (&$letters){
    $letters = $q->get()->unique();
}]);
```

However this does not seem to establish the relationship correctly.

What is the best way to access `D` through `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load `letters` relationship into `Book` you should do something like that with standard relationships:

**Relationships:**

```
Book:

paragraps -> hasMany

Paragraph:

sentences -> hasMany

Sentence:

letters -> hasMany
```

**Getting book with letters**

```
$bookId = 1; // sample book id
$book = Book::with('paragraphs.sentences.letters')->find($bookId);
```

And now to display all letters you could use:

```
foreach ($book->paragraphs as $paragraph)  {
     foreach ($paragaph->sentences as $sentence) {
         foreach ($sentence->letters as $letter) {
            echo $letter->id;
         }
     }      
}
```

I don't know what for you use this structure, but depending on usage, maybe you should also duplicate somehow information in your database. For example for `letters` maybe you should also add `book_id` column and then you could get all books letters using simple `$book->letters` but everything depends on how you use your application.

Comment: So that's how I have the relationship loaded now, but I was trying to get all letters that belong to a book through paragraphs and sentences. I was doing the loop before and pushing into an array but this causes problems because I also have the transliteration of those letters as another table that I need to access. This would mean that I would have to then loop letters again and then do `Letter::with('transliterated')->find($letter->id);` to get each of those which will result in several more queries if I'm not incorrect?

Comment: Yes, so probably as I said you could consider assigning letters also to books for easier maintaining such relationship

Comment: So you're saying that the `letters` model should also have a `public function books(){ return $this->belongsToMany('book') }` ?

Comment: Looking at current table, it should be rather `book() {return $this->belongsTo('book); }` because at the moment letter belongs to sentence so it also belongs to book but maybe you created this in wrong way and it really should be many-to-many relationship

Comment: Understood. Perhaps that's the case. Appreciate the advisement.